# correct setup of apache to handle multiple domains

Tags: apache, centos

hello i have 2 domains domain1.com,domain2.com
both are in the same server under domain1.com
i want to set the VirtualHost to handle them both

like this:

```
<VirtualHost domain1.com:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName domain1.com
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
ServerName domain2.com
<Directory /var/www/domain2>
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>.
```

but for some reason the server send me only to the first one

i also tryed it like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName domain1.com
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
ServerName domain2.com
<Directory /var/www/domain2>
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>.
```

anyone have any idea how to fix this problem ?

Comment: What does your log files say? What you say is that `http://domain2.com` will end up in `/var/www/html/`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `NameVirtualHost` directive.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName domain1.com
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
  ServerName domain2.com
  <Directory /var/www/domain2>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Without it your first `VirtualHost` will be used for all access when using name-based virtual hosting.